# Pseudo element ::before causing horizontal scroll bar

Tags: css, overflow, pseudo-element, pseudo-class

I'm having an issue getting rid of a horizontal scroll bar. I have my design setup with the sizing and positioning right, but I just want the overflow of the ::before image element trick to be hidden.

you can see what I mean here:
http://192.99.37.125/~uptownlounge/

I tried adding overflow-x: hidden; to the body element, but it gets messed up on mobile. any other ideas??

Comment: Post a minimal part of the html/CSS that reproduce the issue

Answer (score 1):

Please use `width:100%;` for mobile device with this selector: `#dots-dark::before{}`

Then the `overflow` issue will be fixed.

```
#dots-dark::before {
   background-color: transparent;
   background-image: url("https://s3.amazonaws.com/webdiner/dots-red-top-arrow.png");
   background-position: top center;
   background-repeat: no-repeat;
   background-size: auto;
   position: absolute;
   content: " ";
   height: 131px;
   display: inline;
   width: 100%;
   left: 127%;
   top: -131px;
   margin-left: -804px; 
}
```

Comment: That won't work. it will break the centering of the absolute position.

Comment: ok,can you try small background image and decrease width according to to device width?

Answer (score 0):

Set margin and padding = 0 for all the elements using * selector `

```
*{
margin:0;
padding:0;
}
```

`

Comment: I'm not sure that's a healthy solution.

Comment: Though this may be a solution to the problem, please try to explain the cause of the problem and how this solution helps fixes it.